# Как мне сделать такой вывод кнопок навигации

Tags: php

текущая страница находится в переменной $this->page общее количество нахоится в переменной $this->count лимит вывода на странице находится в переменной $this->config->count_on_page всё выводится, всё перключается, но мне нужен формат вывода ссылок не подряд все, у меня все подряд выводятся, а именно как в написал выше как это сделать?
    Первая страница     Предыдущая страница     4   5   6   8   9   Следующая     страница  Последняя страница

Comment: тема закрыта зделано

Comment: @jobananas, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Comment: это дублированая тема